# Decrypt zip encrypted with ruby using the mac command line

Tags: ruby, openssl

I'm facing an issue where I'm unable to decrypt a file encrypted in Ruby on my Mac.

Using the following Ruby code, I encrypted a zip file using AES encryption:

```rb
require 'openssl'

key = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-256-CBC').random_key
iv = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-256-CBC').random_iv

key_hex = key.unpack('H*').first
iv_hex = iv.unpack('H*').first

puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_LIBRARY_VERSION # OpenSSL 1.1.1t  7 Feb 2023
puts "Key: #{key_hex}"
puts "IV:  #{iv_hex}"

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-256-CBC').encrypt
cipher.key = key
cipher.iv = iv
binary = cipher.update(data) + cipher.final
binary.unpack1('H*')
```

Subsequently, I am trying to decrypt the created binary file using the Mac OS Terminal:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1s  1 Nov 2022
$ openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -K <key_hex> -iv <iv_hex> -in encrypted > decrypted.zip
```

However, a "bad decrypt" error occurs, and I cannot decrypt it:

```
bad decrypt
4705359360:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:612:
```

Please tell me the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure to use the correct data representation expected by the `openssl` command. It expects the encrypted data in its raw form, not hex encoded.

It appears that you have put the hex-encoded version of encrypted data into your encoded file (i.e. the result of your last ruby statement). Instead, you to put the contents of your `binary` variable into your `encrypted` file (i.e. the result of the previous ruby statement).

Comment: Thank you for guiding me! It worked just as intended!